# Join Multiple Lines Plugin creates extra lines

Tags: line, vector-layer, qchainage

I am using "Join Multiple Lines" plugin before using QChainage because I am getting extra points that aren't spaced properly.  When I use "Join Multiple Lines" it creates extra lines (strait connecting lines) to my file.  Do I need to cleanup my geometry somehow before running "Join Multiple Lines"?[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  Seems using "Dissolve" resolved my issue without having to use "Join Multiple Lines"